# How to change directory for MultiBit HD wallet file away from C:\?

Tags: wallet, multibit

I know the seed is all I need to recover coins, and all I need to recover coins is the 12 words passphrase, etc. etc.

But, what I really want, for various reasons, is to be able to move my wallet for MultiBit HD (I think it’s the one called `multibit.wallet`) from now:

`C:\Users\<your name>\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin`
to a new place which could be a USB drive, an encrypted drive etc.

I can easily do so using Bitcoin Core client and also on MultiBit Classic this was and is easy. But how to I move the MultiBit HD wallet from `C:\` where I really don´t like to have it?

I even installed MultiBit HD on another disk `E:\` - but still the software installs the wallet at `C:\Users\<your name>\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin`
I´ve been searching around here and there but not really found an answer.

Could somebody help me here?